# How to reduce height of list item in dialog box?

Tags: android

I have list in AlertDialog. I used setItems to show array for each list item. But, the height of each item in the list is too big. Is there anyway to reduce height of the list item in dialog box?

Comment: may be you need to use customList in dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you must create XML layout lets called row .xml contain list component,

then you will inflater the row layout ,

after you can change list height inside dialog from xml layout as you wish .

you can try this :

```
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); LayoutInflater inflater =
   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View v = inflater.inflate
   (R.layout.row, null, false); dialog .setContentView(v);
   dialog .show();
```

then your xml layout :

```
  <TexView
    android:id="@+id/YOUR LIST"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="your height" >
  </TextView>
```

hope this help

Comment: Dose this reduce list item? It seems that it reduces listview. Before I try, I would like to know.

Comment: @user1301568 just try it , any stack reply me

Comment: I am new to XML. There is compile error in xml. Error seems listview cannot be inside scrollview. Actually, I don't want scroll bar. That is the reason I want to reduce height.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my question. I have to study more.